# Difference of two convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, stochastic-calculus

This is an exercise from a probability textbook on Ito's formula, basically Ito's formula extends to functions of this type.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f$ is twice differentiable everywhere except on a set $\{a_1,...a_k\}$. At these isolated points, $f'(a_n+)$ $f'(a_n-)$ $f''(a_n+)$ and $f''(a_n-)$ exists. (These are the left and right limits of $f'$ and $f''$ at these points.)

The question is: how can we show such a function is the difference of two convex functions.

I would also be interested in the following question:

Which conditions could we have weakened such that it is still the difference of two convex functions?

Comment: Maybe you can show that $f'$ is of bounded variation hence can be written as the difference of two increasing functions?

Comment: If $f(x)=\int_0^x t^2\sin(1/t^2)dt$, then $f$ is twice differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is not of bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Nice. Then I guess the answer is negative.The derivative of convex functions is increasing, hence your $f$ cannot be expressed as the difference of two convex functions.

Comment: I think in the hypothesis we also need the limits to exist finitely.